# Conditionals in css?

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements

Is it possible to use some form of conditionals?

Building a new design style out in code.

Usually the `<h1>` tag has a small line underneath it.
The `<h2>` tag does as well but when the `<h1>` is present the `<h2>` tag should not have a line underneath it.

```css
h1:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background-color: green;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width:50px
}

h2:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background-color: orange;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width:30px
}
```

```html
<h1>H1 title</h1> 

<h2>So now this H2 title should not have a line since there is a h1 above it.</h2>
```

Comment: You can use the selector `h1 + h2:after`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~` for this, as long as both headings share the same parent element.

If you only want the `h2` that **directly** follows the `h1` to not have it, use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+` instead.

Please note that `:after` is old CSS 2.1 syntax. Please use CSS3's `::after` instead.

```css
h1::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background-color: green;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 50px
}

h2::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background-color: orange;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 30px
}

h1~h2::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>H1 title</h1>

  <h2>So now this H2 title should not have a line since there is a h1 above it.</h2>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>So now this H2 title should have a line since there is no h1 above it.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can i do that when they are not in the same parent element?

Comment: @Lucas With CSS means only, you cannot. You'd have to apply classes then. It cannot be achieved based on markup structure alone then.